# Google Maps não carrega os pontos cadastrados (Java)

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, android-activity, localização

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou usando o Google Maps no meu app e estava fucionando antes mas parou de funcionar.

**O app quebra enquanto o mapa está sendo carregado**. Já pesquisei bastante na internet e nenhuma solução resolveu o problema.

Pelo o pouco que entendi **é como se o app não estivesse conseguindo setar os pontos de localização no mapa** mas não tenho certeza se é esse é o problema.

Tenho a Google Maps API key dentro do projeto.

**Segue código e log abaixo.**

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_shop"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/achei_aqui_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
   <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>

    <activity android:name="com.acheiAqui.View.SplashScreenActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.acheiAqui.View.HomeActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.acheiAqui.Control.LoginActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.acheiAqui.Control.RegisterUserActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.acheiAqui.Control.RegisterInfoShopActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.acheiAqui.Control.RegisterFoodListActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.acheiAqui.Control.RegisterLocationActivity" />
    <activity android:name="com.acheiAqui.View.ProfileShopActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
</application>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "acheiaqui.com.acheiaqui"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'

 //   implementation group: 'com.android.tools.build', name: 'gradle', version: '3.2.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.4.0'

    implementation group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-maps', version: '17.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-location', version: '17.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-analytics', version: '17.0.0'
    implementation group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-nearby', version: '17.0.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    //Picaso for Photos
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.picasso', name: 'picasso', version: '2.8'

    //Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
package com.acheiAqui.View;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.Settings;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.acheiAqui.Control.LoginActivity;
import com.acheiAqui.Model.Shop;
import com.acheiAqui.Control.RegisterInfoShopActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

import acheiaqui.com.acheiAqui.R;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker currentLocationMaker;
    private LatLng currentLocationLatLong;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.getExtras();
        if(intent.hasExtra("success")){
            Toast.makeText(this, intent.getStringExtra("success"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        startGettingLocations();
        getMarkers();
    }

    //funcao que carrega o mapa quando o aplicativo e aberto
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        mMap = googleMap;
        /*
        MarkerOptions markerShop = new MarkerOptions();
        markerShop.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_shop));
        MarkerOptions markerAtualLocation = new MarkerOptions();
        markerAtualLocation.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_shop_round));*/

    }

    //funcao que pega a localizacao atual do cliente, caso este permita que sua localizacao seja utilizada,
    // plota um marcador no mapa e coloca foco do mapa nessa atual localizacao
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        //quando a localizacao atual do usuario mudar, ele retira o marcador anterior, caso tenha existido, e cria outro
        if (currentLocationMaker != null) {
            currentLocationMaker.remove();
        }
        //adiciona o marcador com a localizacao atual do usuario
        currentLocationLatLong = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(currentLocationLatLong);
        markerOptions.title("Localização atual");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));

        currentLocationMaker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        currentLocationMaker.setDraggable(true); //permite que o marcador possa ser trocado de lugar

        //quando a localizacao atual do usuario muda, o foco do mapa muda para o ponto atual do usuario e aumenta
        //o zoom do mapa, mostrando mais detalhes do mesmo
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().zoom(17).target(currentLocationLatLong).build();
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        //Toast.makeText(this, "Localização atualizada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getMarkers();
    }


    private ArrayList<String> findUnAskedPermissions(ArrayList<String> wanted) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String perm : wanted) {
            if (!hasPermission(perm)) {
                result.add(perm);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    private boolean hasPermission(String permission) {
        if (canAskPermission()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                return (checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    //caso a versao do celular seja maior que a marshmallow, o aplicativo pergunta se pode usar a localizacao
    //do usuario, caso contrario, ele ja tem essa informacao a partir das confifuracoes do arquivo do manifest
    private boolean canAskPermission() {
        return (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1);
    }

    //funcao que verifica se o GPS do usuario esta ativado, e caso nao esteja, perguna ao mesmo se deseja ativa-lo
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS desativado!");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Ativar GPS?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    //funcao que pega a localizaao atual do usuario, via GPS ou via Internet
    private void startGettingLocations() {

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        boolean isGPS = false;
        if (lm != null) {
            isGPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        boolean isNetwork = false;
        if (lm != null) {
            isNetwork = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        boolean canGetLocation = true;
        int ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT = 101;
        long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;// Distance in meters
        long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 10;// Time in milliseconds

        ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> permissionsToRequest;

        permissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        permissions.add(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        permissionsToRequest = findUnAskedPermissions(permissions);

        //Verifica se o GPS ou Internet do usuario esta ligada, caso nao esteja, pergunta se o mesmo deseja ativa-la
        if (!isGPS && !isNetwork) {
            showSettingsAlert();
        } else {

            //verifica permissoes de uso do GPS para versoes anteriores ao marshmallow
            //para versoes anteriores ao marshmallow, a localizacao ja pode ser adquirida a partir da
            //configucao do arquivo do manifest
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (permissionsToRequest.size() > 0) {
                    requestPermissions(permissionsToRequest.toArray(new String[permissionsToRequest.size()]),
                            ALL_PERMISSIONS_RESULT);
                    canGetLocation = false;
                }
            }
        }


        //verfica se a permissao para utilizar a localizacao foi concedida
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Permissão negada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        //atualiza a localizacao do usuario, a partir do GPS ou Intenet
        if (canGetLocation) {
            if (isGPS) lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
            else if (isNetwork) {
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Não é possível obter a localização", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void getMarkers(){
        mDatabase.child("shop").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
                new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //Get map of users in datasnapshot
                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                            getAllLocations((Map<String,Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        //handle databaseError
                    }
                });
    }

    private void getAllLocations(Map<String, Object> locations) {


        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : locations.entrySet()) {
            Shop shop = new Shop();
            Map singleLocation = (Map) entry.getValue();
            shop.setName((String) singleLocation.get("name"));
            shop.setInfo((String) singleLocation.get("info"));
            shop.setId((String) singleLocation.get("id"));
            shop.setReference((String) singleLocation.get("reference"));
            shop.setFood((String) singleLocation.get("food"));
            shop.setLatitude((Double) singleLocation.get("latitude"));
            shop.setLongitude((Double) singleLocation.get("longitude"));
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(shop.getLatitude(), shop.getLongitude());
            addGreenMarker(shop, latLng).setTag(shop);
            mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                    Shop actualShop = (Shop) marker.getTag();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProfileShopActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name", actualShop.getName());
                        intent.putExtra("info", actualShop.getInfo());
                        intent.putExtra("id", actualShop.getId());
                        intent.putExtra("reference", actualShop.getReference());
                        intent.putExtra("food", actualShop.getFood());
                        startActivity(intent);

                }
            });


        }


    }

    private Marker addGreenMarker(final Shop shop, LatLng latLng) {


        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title(shop.getName());
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));

        Marker shopMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        return shopMarker;
    }


    //funcoes padroes da classe LocationListerner. Nao foi necessario sobrescreve-las para manipular o mapa
    //e a localizacao atual do usuario
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider,int status, Bundle extras){

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

    }

    public void registerNewShop(View view){

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Shop.java**

```
package com.acheiAqui.Model;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class Shop
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String info;
    private String reference;
    private String food;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public Shop(String name, String info, String reference, String food, double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.info = info;
        this.reference = reference;
        this.food = food;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Shop(){

    }

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    public String getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.acheiAqui.View.HomeActivity">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.acheiAqui.View.HomeActivity" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="registerNewShop"
        android:rotation="0"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_input_add"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Log do Android Studio**

```
020-09-28 17:52:46.867 29307-29307/? E/cr_BTSPrefs: No data found for task id: 53
2020-09-28 17:52:46.868 29307-29307/? E/cr_BkgrdTaskScheduler: Task cannot be canceled because no data was found instorage or data was invalid
2020-09-28 17:52:55.538 22149-22149/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadJobService has leaked ServiceConnection android.media.MediaScannerConnection@1695918 that was originally bound here
    android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadJobService has leaked ServiceConnection android.media.MediaScannerConnection@1695918 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1619)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1511)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1674)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1627)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:698)
        at android.media.MediaScannerConnection.connect(MediaScannerConnection.java:119)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadScanner.requestScan(DownloadScanner.java:140)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadScanner.requestScanBlocking(DownloadScanner.java:85)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadThread.run(DownloadThread.java:434)
2020-09-28 17:52:55.570 22149-29482/? E/MediaScannerService: Exception in handleMessage
    java.lang.NullPointerException: url
        at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:128)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:1677)
        at com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadScanner.onScanCompleted(DownloadScanner.java:184)
        at android.media.MediaScannerConnection$1.scanCompleted(MediaScannerConnection.java:53)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(MediaScannerService.java:226)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService.run(MediaScannerService.java:162)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-09-28 17:52:55.796 1126-1126/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/29376/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2020-09-28 17:52:55.797 1126-1126/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/29361/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2020-09-28 17:52:55.799 1126-1126/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/29361/oom_score_adj; errno=22android.media.MediaScannerConnection$1.scanCompleted(MediaScannerConnection.java:53)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(MediaScannerService.java:226)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerService.run(MediaScannerService.java:162)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2020-09-28 17:52:55.796 1126-1126/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/29376/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2020-09-28 17:52:55.797 1126-1126/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/29361/oom_score_adj; errno=22
2020-09-28 17:52:55.799 1126-1126/? E/lowmemorykiller: Error writing /proc/29361/oom_score_adj; errno=22

2020-09-28 17:54:43.345 29792-29792/acheiaqui.com.acheiaqui E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: acheiaqui.com.acheiaqui, PID: 29792
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
        at com.acheiAqui.View.HomeActivity.getAllLocations(HomeActivity.java:254)
        at com.acheiAqui.View.HomeActivity.access$000(HomeActivity.java:43)
        at com.acheiAqui.View.HomeActivity$3.onDataChange(HomeActivity.java:232)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:179)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6912)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:860)
```

Comment: Posta a pergunta nesse site: https://android.stackexchange.com/ acho que lá ela tera mais chances de ser respondida(o site é em inglês)

Comment: Pode ser o problema da conexão com a Internet, se não houver um grande problema. Já enfrentei o mesmo tipo de problema algumas vezes. Por causa da minha má conexão com a Internet. O Google Maps não está carregando bem.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique os locais para valores `null`, você está obtendo valor `null` do GPS. Isso pode acontecer também no dispositivo.

Na linha 254 `latitude` é `null` como o 'stacktrace' informa.

O erro vem na linha 254, quando a latitude da localização (valor `null`) acumula para `Double` conversão, o que é ilegal para valor `null`.

```
shop.setLatitude((Double) singleLocation.get("latitude"));
```

Caso não haja localização do GPS em algum ponto do tempo, pode acabar aqui com valores `null` dentro do objeto `Location`:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

A verificação de valores `null` deve ser feita em um dos casos mencionados acima.

*Informação encontrada na resposta em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608632/android-locationmanager-getlastknownlocation-returns-null/1609593#1609593*

**Edição:**

Eu li mais documentação, e diz que `getLocation( )`

> a) sempre retorna um valor (não null, se eu li bem) e
>
> b) longitude + latitude são sempre válidos.

É o mais possível que seu banco de dados tem valores de localização vazios (latitude e longitude). O `Map` está lendo do banco de dados em `getAllLocations( )` inclui esses valores `null`.

Comment: Então os valores do banco de dados são válidos porque eu já tinha cadastrado antes. Eu to achando que está tendo algum problema para pegar a localização atual e por isso o app quebra. Mas não estou sabendo em que parte do código isso está acontecendo.